# Toggle in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to expand a span after an ajax refresh of my page. below is the code written in the callback function of my ajax call. It is not working.

```
$('#ship_toggleDimension').css('display','block');
$('#ship_toggleDimensionimg').attr("src", "../../resources/base/images/drop_icon2.png");
return false;
```

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Have you debugged to ensure that the code is in fact running?

Comment: Define 'not working'. Can you put together a jsFiddle replicating the issue?

Comment: What error do you see in console. Try "$('#ship_toggleDimension')" in console to see whether you get the element at all

Comment: @lvil If he types that into the console, he'll get an `Object`. You need to check `$('#ship_toggleDimension').length`...

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the script from the correct path so that `../../resources/base/images/drop_icon2.png` correctly links to the image?

Comment: Create a fiddle please

Comment: @BenM: `$('#ship_toggleDimension');` is enough to check if it is a valid element (well, certainly in Chrome anyway)

Comment: Not it isn't, because it returns an array, not a boolean...

Comment: @BenM Sorry, got used to chrome console, it shows what is inside the arrat, smth like "[<a....></a>,<a...></a>....]"

Comment: @BenM: It returns an empty array if the element does not exist, or a populated array if there is a match. It doesn't need to be a boolean value for the eye to see if the match is valid or not. Not saying `length` isn't better, but this approach does work

Comment: Actually , my callback function executes and page is getting referesh afterwards. due to which the default css, display: none excutes and span is getting hided.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the browser to refresh the image by passing an extra variable 
 make sure the image path is correct.

```
somefunction()
 {
 d = new Date();
 $('#ship_toggleDimension').css('display','block');
 $('#ship_toggleDimensionimg').attr("src", "../../resources/base/images/drop_icon2.png"+d.getTime());
 return false;
 }
```

Comment: You are taking a bit of a guess here, we don't even know what the actually problem is yet...